# Launching UFT application makes Cortana use a lot more CPU and react a lot slower

Tags: hp-uft, cortana, uft14

I'm using version 14.03.

Anytime I open UFT, Cortana, or even Windows Shell Experience Host if I remove Cortana, starts being very slow and CPU hungry.  It stays that way until I log off or reboot.  Cortana is the process that handles the start menu and searches so it's very noticeable when it is slower.

the installation guide mentions that Cortana should be disabled during UFT install, which I tried.  It seemed to have fixed the issue at first, Cortana stayed responsive for a while after I opened UFT but it ended up going back to being slow later on.  Now, after a reboot, it reverted back to the old behaviour of being slow as soon as UFT is launched

Another thing worth noting is that as soon as I uninstall UFT, Cortana works well again (no reboot).

What could be causing this?

Comment: opened related question on SuperUser https://superuser.com/questions/1509589/cortana-starts-being-slow-and-laggy-after-launch-of-the-uft-unified-functional?noredirect=1#comment2282619_1509589

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd suggest moving this subject to https://superuser.com/ community.
2. It indeed sounds like a real conflict between `Unified Functional Testing` and `Cortana`. not sure that you, as an end-user, can solve it.

   - First, I'd suggest the obvious - contact support of both companies, and update to the latest versions.
   - Second, try to collect as much information as you can:

     - [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) - filter by the relevant processes (`Cortana` process name is `SearchUI.exe`, but I don't know about `UTF`).
     - Microsoft Event Viewer - try to seek for events in the exact time of the issue.